# DNS MX records on doman nameservers differ

Tags: mx-record, dns-zone, cpanel

I have a domain... enertron.com.ar

This domains is hosted on a cPanel server. To point the domain to that server I use two nameservers:

ns13.hostmar.com
ns14.hostmar.com

Just as the hosting providers asks.

I've updated the mx records on cpanel to point to Google (G Suite).

When I dig ns13.hostmar.com for MX records the response is OK.
When I dig ns14.hostmar.com for MX records the response is WRONG ("normal" mx records instead on Google ones).

Some of the email sent to the domain is being rejected.

Shouln't the hosting provider update both nameservers at the same time? It's OK for one server update later than the other?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can confirm what you are saying is accurate. Since you have no control over the DNS servers in question, you need to contact the host in charge of those DNS servers and see what is going on.  The other possibility is that you just made this change within the past hour or two and I'm sure you probably saw a warning that these changes can take several hours to replicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary server ns13 is up-to-date, but your secondary (ns14) did not transfered the zone correctly. The serial in the SOA RR of your zone in ns14 should be 2017070603 (the value registered in the primary server), but it is 2017072017, as you can see with dig:

```
% dig @ns14.hostmar.com enertron.com.ar. soa +short

ns13.hostmar.com. jose.seisto.com. **2017070603** 3600 7200 1209600 86400

% dig @ns13.hostmar.com enertron.com.ar. soa +short

 ns13.hostmar.com. jose.seisto.com. **2017072017** 3600 7200 1209600 86400
```

You should check the reason why the zone transfer does not work. After a correct zone transfer, your MX will be OK.